# Find and replace rows with similar value in one column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql-server, select, row

I want to find the rows which are similar to each other, and replace them with a new row. My table looks like this:

```
OrderID  |  Price  | Minimum Number | Maximum Number | Volume

1         45        2                 10                250 

2         46        2                 10                250

3         60        2                 10                250
```

"Similar" in this context means that the rows that have same Maximum Number, Minimum Number, and Volume. Prices can be different, but the difference can be at most 2.

In this example, orders with OrderID of 1 and 2 are similar, but 3 is not (since even if it has same Minimum Number, Maximum Number, and Volume, its price is not within 2 units from orders 1 and 2).

Then, I want orders 1 and 2 be replaced by a new order, let's say OrderID 4, which has same Minimum Number and Maximum Number. Its Volume hass to be sum of volumes of the orders it is replacing. Its price can be the Price of any of the previous orders that will be deleted in the output table (45 or 46 in this example). So, the output for the example above would be:

```
OrderID  |  Price  | Minimum Number | Maximum Number | Volume 

4         45        2                 10                500

3         60        2                 10                250
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this in SQL Server 2012 or Oracle.  The idea is to use `lag()` to find where groups should begin and end and then aggregate.

```
select min(id) as id, min(price) as price, MinimumNumber, MaximumNumber, sum(Volume)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_price < price - 2 then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by MinimumNumber, MaximumNumber, Volume order by price) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(price) over (partition by MinimumNumber, MaximumNumber, Volume
                                    order by price
                                   ) as prev_price
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, price, MinimumNumber, MaximumNumber;
```

The only issue is the setting of the `id`.  I'm not sure what the exact rule is for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It almost works. The only problem is when the price of the row with lower ID is more than the price of the row with higher ID. In other words, it only works correct when the similar rows have both increasing IDs and increasing Prices.
For the example below:
OrderID  |  Price  | Minimum Number | Maximum Number | Volume 

1         45        2                 10                250

2         44        2                 10                250

grp is 1 for order 1, and 0 for order 2, and therefore not considered as similar rows, but it works if we swap the prices.

Comment: @gorodon-linoff: In fact the output is correct only when there are two identical rows (even prices must be identical). Not when two (or several) similar rows (price difference < 2). I guess "grp" is not being calculated correctly.

Comment: @user1777530 . . . I don't understand the issue.  Your problem statement says *nothing* about `OrderId` being involved with the definition of similarity, and I'm pretty sure this method works for the question as stated.  I would suggest that you ask another question, clarifying your real problem.  Along the way, add a SQL Fiddle with sample data.